# How to send mail in zend2.2 using DKIM

Tags: php, zend-framework, dkim

I am new to DKIM concept. I have been provided private and public keys of DKIM.

Do I need to make any changes in my code or just have to setup the domain keys for my server ?

If I do need to make the changes what should I do for enabling DKIM in my mails.

I am using zend 2.2 and php 5.3.3
I got a link https://github.com/fastnloud/zf2-dkim but it will be requiring minimum zend 2.3.
Thanks in advance.